# Why is my hero image zoomed in? Parallax scrolling

Tags: css, parallax

The effect works fine, but the image is zoomed in on. Any clue as to why?

```
    #hero{
    background-image:url(../images/metalWorx_hero.jpg);
    width:1020px;
    min-height:398px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover; 
     }
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, **background-sizing: cover;** is the reason why your background image seems "zoomed" as it is making the background image so big that it fully fits over its container. What happens on your case (feeling like its being zoomed in) is that the aspect ratio of the background isnt the same as the aspect ratio of the container. Instead of stretching the background image, background-sizing: cover will *oversize* the background so much until it covers everything up, leaving no gaps, but the "zooming" might happen.

Here is an illustration of the reason, as I know how bad my english :D

[image: Illustration]

So you can see, the background image will be resized that it fits for the height, but because of the aspect ratio, both of the sides will go out of the container.

Edit #2 - Added some more informations and help

Depending on the real aspect ratios and sizes there are different solutions to it. The "quick and dirty solution" is to use background-size but instead of setting it to "cover", we will set its width and height to 100%. Code:

```
#hero{
  background-image:url(../images/metalWorx_hero.jpg);
  width:1020px;
  min-height:398px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%; /* Set width and height to 100% */
}
```

Its a very simple "fix", but its obvious what can happen when the aspect ratio gets distorted:

[image: web designers nightmare - photograph: milos, yeah it was scary]

## **Real and only way to fix it ;)**

If you really want to fix it, you should make sure that your container and background image have about the same aspect ratio and then going back to background-size: cover; (just as in your first post)

Comment: For whatever reason doing that makes for a big white space above the image.

Comment: Can we see the Javascript for the parallax scrolling?

Comment: I updated the post again with some more informations and help on how you could fix it. :) @LarsBeck Who are you asking? And btw, nobody did ever mention JavaScript on this question. ;)

Comment: I have no idea, guess it was the parallax tag (: